# Is the CA Middle Class Tax Refund (MCTR) taxable?

Tags: taxes, california

Seems to be some confusion whether federal taxes are due. I did receive a form 1099-MISC from CA. FreeTaxUSA says it's exempt from CA taxes but federal is due, while TurboTax says it's exempt from both.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154929/are-colorado-tabor-refunds-taxable-for-those-who-deduct-state-sales-tax

Comment: Apparently IRS is planning on issuing a statement on the matter sometime next week (Feb 6-10).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this IRS guidance](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/irs-issues-guidance-on-state-tax-payments-to-help-taxpayers), you can treat it as not taxable, at least for the 2022 tax year:

> Payments from the following states fall in this category and the IRS
> will not challenge the treatment of these payments as excludable for
> federal income tax purposes in 2022.
>
> [...]
>
> - California
>
> [...]
>
> For a list of the specific payments to which this applies, please see this chart.

And the [chart](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/state-payments) includes:

> California
>
> Middle Class Tax Refund